# How to insert socat sniffing between pyserial and actual serial port

Tags: linux, python-3.x, serial-port, pyserial, socat

I have an app written in python3 that uses pyserial (python3-serial) to communicate with another processor via serial cable. And I'm losing some responses. I have a tap on the line itself and have determined that the responses are indeed being placed on the wire.

So I wanted to sniff the port at a low linux level to see if the responses are showing up there. My python3 apps uses something like

```
port = serial.Serial(path, baudrate=115200, timeout=0)
```

where `path` is something like `_port_TD200_` which is a symlink to `\dev\ttyS3`.

My general approach was to change that link, so that it points at a virtual port, and then bridge the real port to the virtual port. So I used `ln -sf` to relink the `_port_TD200_` to `/tmp/ttyV0` and then run this

```
sudo socat /dev/ttyS3,raw,echo=0 SYSTEM:'tee input.txt | socat - "PTY,link=/tmp/ttyV0,raw,echo=0,waitslave" | tee output.txt'
```

However, when I try to restart the service that runs the pyserial app... it chokes on the change:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 265, in open
     self.fd = os.open(self.portstr, os.O_RDWR | os.O_NOCTTY | os.O_NONBLOCK)
 PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/opt/pilot/_port_TD200_'
 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/opt/pilot/radio.py", line 19, in __init__
     self.port = serial.Serial(path, baudrate=115200, timeout=0)
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialutil.py", line 236, in __init__
     self.open()
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 268, in open
     raise SerialException(msg.errno, "could not open port {}: {}".format(self._port, msg))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: [Errno 13] could not open port /opt/pilot/_port_TD200_: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/opt/pilot/_port_TD200_'
```

I have a *guess* that the pyserial open machinery which opens a file descriptor, but ALSO does `setserial` like things, is not happy because `/tmp/ttyV0` is not enough of a real serial port. Is this correct? If so, is there a way to modify the `socat` incantation to make it possible?

Or is it something else? I admit I don't really understand the `socat` incantation. I pulled it from [this stack exchange question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12359/how-can-i-monitor-serial-port-traffic)...